# Behaviour of the poles in transfer function $H(s)$, given system properties

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, transfer-function

If a linear system is causal and its impulse response is an energy signal. What's the behaviour of the poles of $s$-domain transfer function $H(s)$?

Comment: This looks like a homework question, which is OK. In this case we just ask you to add your own thoughts and doubts to the question, so we can understand what your problem is. The question actually boils down to find the region in the $s$-plane where the poles of a causal and stable system are located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ROC can be chosen to make the transfer function causal and/or stable depending on the pole/zero plot. If the ROC extends outward from the outermost pole, then the system is causal.